Spawn 2 function calls from Registration method
I have a registration class in PHP which just creates the user into the database.
But there are 2 other external API calls in this Register class - one using ConvertKit's SDK and the other one using Partnero's SDK which is making the registration a bit slow.
Is there a way to spawn these 2 function calls so that after creating the user in the database it doesn't wait for the API calls to get over with to continue to the redirect page ?
Using vanilla core PHP and not using a framework like Laravel of sorts.

One approach is to have your script set a flag (database, file, whatever) with whatever details are needed by the other 2 APIs.  At some later time a separate script which runs periodically (eg cron) checks for those flags, and processes any queued up.  Search for "php queues" for more.

Main issue: synchronization into asynchrony
Core note: how to ensure successful execution after asynchronous processing, error and failure handling
Solutions:
CURL request

create one or two additional api interfaces for calling these two functions
After creating the user into the database, make a no-wait request via curl, like so

    public function CurlRun($UniqueID, $CronTime)
    {
        $Url = "{$_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME']}://{$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']}?Api=User&Action=RegisterAfter&UID=10000";

        $stream = @fopen($Url, 'r', false, stream_context_create(
            [
                'http' => ['timeout' => 0.01]
            ]
        ));
        if ($stream)
            @fclose($stream);
    }


Return success without waiting for the request to complete.
Call your additional processing in the RegisterAfter function, and actually pay attention to whether you need to retry if it fails or send an error e-mail to let you know what went wrong.

Using queue tasks

Try the simplest Redis queue, create a list structure in redis, say called Jobs.
after registering a user, push a task into the redis Jobs via lpush, which contains the user id and other information you need, it can be a json array.
create an additional interface, say called Consumer, to consume the queued tasks, it takes the task out of the Jobs via rPop, that is to say, it executes your two additional functions, and then deletes it, and you need to pay attention to the error handling, because it is not synchronized, you need some other way to know if it succeeds or fails to retry or so on, which can be extended by you. This is all up to you.
Create a timed script on the server Crontab, depending on you, it can be executed once a minute or five minutes, each time the Consumer function is requested.

Deferred Periodic Execution
If you are in a business where there is no information related to the additional interface that needs to be displayed immediately after the user registers

you can just execute the storage database at registration time and add a field to identify whether the additional request has been completed or not
or use the Crontab, depending on your business, for example at 0:00 or several times a day, to scan for all outstanding users, make requests for additional functions and add additional information.

